# Correct version for windows server 2007 of SSMS

Tags: ssms

I need to install a GUI interfaze for SQL server in a Windows Server 2007 machine, my problem is that the oldest version I see of SSMS in microsoft website is 15, and it need Widows Server 2008. This is a production enviroment and I shoudn't change the OS.
The SQL server is 2005.

Anyone know if I can find a older version of SSMS?
Other programs so I can manage my db with a GUI?

Comment: There is no Windows Server 2007. There was a Windows Server 2008, and prior to that was 2003. 2003 hasn't been supported at all for years, and 2008 reached End of Life at the very start of this year; you should be looking at upgrade paths ASAP. As for what version of SSMS, I *think* that up to SSMS 2017 was supported on Server 2008/Windows 7. If you're using 2003, then probably at best SSMS 2012, which comes with the installation media for SQL Server 2012; it was not distributed separately like more recent versions.

Comment: You're right, I was using Windows Server Standart, I missunderstood the copyright year (2007)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I post it here just if someone comes with this problem:

https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=8961

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express (SSMSE) is intended for Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

Comment: SQL Server 2005 hit End of Life even longer ago. You **need** to get that (those?) server(s) upgraded asap. I hope that they don't have access to the WAN, as if so they are a security risk waiting to happen.

Comment: I'm doing a integration of that server with a website... I am not those systems admin though we have suggested the chage. Thaks for the info ^^

Comment: *"I'm doing a integration of that server with a website"* That is incredibly dangerous then; SQL Server 2005 has known security vulnerabilities and Windows Server 2008 isn't receiving security updates any more so it'll only be a matter of time before one is found (if not already). The *last* thing you should be using End of Life software for is websites.